# list of lists rather than list of tuples - python

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-itertools

I'm working on a program that will give all combinations of list of values without repetition.  It doesn't matter how the result is sorted so long as both [10, 9, 8] and [8, 9, 10] are not both possible.  So far I have a piece of code that does what I want but I'd like the result to be in list format instead of tuples.  It uses the unordered_tuples function from the sage library but all that does is return a list of lists like so:

```
>from sage.all import unordered_tuples
>tuples = unordered_tuples([10,9,8],2) 
>print tuples
[[8, 8], [8, 9], [8, 10], [9, 9], [9, 10], [10, 10]]
```

And:

```
from itertools import product
def combos():
    dicti = {} 
    index = 0 
    for entry in [1,0,1,0]: 
        dicIndex = str('0')+str(index) 
        print dicIndex 
        if entry == 0: dicti[dicIndex] = [[0]] 
        else: dicti[str('0')+str(index)] = unordered_tuples([10,9,8],entry) 
        index += 1 
    lis = ['00','01','02','03'] 
    value = dicti[lis[0]] 
    print dicti 
    for index in lis[1:]: 
        value = product(value, dicti[index]) 
        if index == lis[-1]: 
            print list(value) 
            print
```

Output:

```
[((([8], [0]), [8]), [0]), ((([8], [0]), [9]), [0]), ((([8], [0]), [10]), [0]), ((([9], [0]), [8]), [0]), ((([9], [0]), [9]), [0]), ((([9], [0]), [10]), [0]), ((([10], [0]), [8]), [0]), ((([10], [0]), [9]), [0]), ((([10], [0]), [10]), [0])]
```

Want:

```
[[[8], [0], [8], [0]], [[8], [0], [9], [0]], [[8], [0], [10], [0]], [[9], [0], [8], [0]], [[9], [0], [9], [0]], [[9], [0], [10], [0]], [[10], [0], [8], [0]], [[10], [0], [9], [0]], [[10], [0], [10], [0]]]
```

Comment: I don't understand neither the input, nor the output.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't either. A co-worker of mine had me ask the question, and this is exactly what I was given. I'll ask her for more details tomorrow to make the question more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

```
output = [[[tuple[0]], [0], [tuple[1]], [0]] for tuple in unordered_tuples([10,9,8],2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when extracting data from a PostgreSQL database. This is the method I used.

```
def tupleToList(t):
    l = []
    for i in xrange(len(t)):
        l.append(list(t[i]))
        pass
    return l
    pass
```

This works for 2D lists. I'm working on implimenting it to 5D lists in your case.